# integration arises

Tags: integration

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-r^{2}/R^{2}}
\sin\left(kr\right)r\,{\rm d}r
\\[3mm]\end{align}

How the  2nd line arises? I can see that $\frac12$ comes from euler theorem but how **$\sin(kRr)$** crises?
\begin{align}
\frac 12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-r^{2}}
\sin\left(kR\,r\right)r\,{\rm d}r
 \end{align}

Comment: Are you leaving something out, such as an assertion that the two integrals are equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the integrand is symmetric about zero to find that

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-r^2/R^2} \sin{(kr)} r dr = \frac 1 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-r^2/R^2} \sin{(kr)} r dr$$

Now make a substitution $u = r/R$, finding that $Rdu = dr$. This leads to

$$\frac 1 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-r^2/R^2} \sin{(kr)} r dr = \frac 1 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} \sin{(kRu)} (Ru)(R du)$$

Finally, rename $u$ as $r$.

Comment: @Did Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

1) Make the change of variables $ r=R \,t $

2) Integrate by parts with $u=\sin(k t R)$.

3) then note that the resulting integral is nothing but the real part of the similar integral

$$ C \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}e^{i \alpha t}dt.$$

Which you can evaluate using [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) by completing the square. Here is the final result

> $$ \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}4\,k{R}^{3}{{\rm e}^{-\frac{1}{4}\,{R}^{2}{k}^{2}}}.  $$